# Tooltip inside bootstrap multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using this [bootstrap multi-select](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect). My goal is to display tooltip when there is a mouseover over the menu items.

It seems the multiselect prevent the tooltip to be displayed.

[**Demo in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ug4gj8tx/)

**HTML**:

```html
<select name="menu[]" id="menu" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Items">...
        <option id='one' value='1' title="Popover one" 
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="content one">1</option>
        <option id='two' value='2' title="Popover two" 
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="content two">2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**JS**:

```js
$('#menu').multiselect({
    maxHeight: 400,
    numberDisplayed: 1,
    nonSelectedText: 'All',
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
});

$("#one").tooltip({
    placement: 'right'
});
$("#two").tooltip({
    placement: 'right'
});
```

How can I achieve tooltip in multiselect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you got [this warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR72Q.png), jsFiddle wasn't joking.  Github really won't work as a CDN because it delivers everything as text.  Once you add the proper libraries ([css](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css) and [js](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js)), you'll see how Bootstrap Multiselect transforms your element.

This original markup:

```html
<select id="menu" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Items">
        <option id='one' value='1'>1</option>
        <option id='two' value='2'>2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Becomes this:

```html
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" >
    <li class="multiselect-item filter"><!-- truncated --></li>
    <li class="multiselect-item group" ><!-- truncated --></li>

    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="1"/> 1
        </label>
    </a></li>

    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="multiselect" value="2"/> 2
        </label>
    </a></li>

</ul>
```

Thus, **the element `#one` is no longer in the picture.**

So the selector for the `tooltip` function will have to change a little. We want to target `li` elements that are children of the `.multiselect-container`.  And we also want to ignore the `.filter` and `.group` elements.  Then just call `tooltip` and compose your `title` however you want.

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0bm03sy4/)

```js
$('.multiselect-container li').not('.filter, .group').tooltip({
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    title: function () {
        // put whatever you want here
        var value = $(this).find('input').val();
        return 'Has Value of ' + value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to add a tool tip the way bootstrap does in this scenario. Bootstrap adds its tooltips to the page by injecting a `<div>` with some content directly after the element you selected. (in your case, #one or #two). Only `<optgroup>` and `<option>` tags are allowed inside a `<select>` tag, other content will not be displayed, which is why your tool tips are not showing up.  Check out this [select element documentation](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

However, if you don't use the bootstrap tooltip plugin here, you will see browser tooltips for the title on the `<option>`s inside the select.

Answer (score 0):

According to the bootstrap tooltip docs, you will need to add the "container: body" option to your tooltips.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

> Tooltips in button groups and input groups require special setting
>   When using tooltips on elements within a .btn-group or an
>   .input-group, you'll have to specify the option container: 'body'
>   (documented below) to avoid unwanted side effects (such as the element
>   growing wider and/or losing its rounded corners when the tooltip is
>   triggered).

In your fiddler session, I noticed that the plugins for the multi-select were causing errors in the console, and after removing the code and references to the multi-select, the tooltips began to show up.

http://jsfiddle.net/ug4gj8tx/1/

```
$("#one").tooltip({container: 'body'});
$("#two").tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

The positioning is a little off, so you may need to play with it to get them to show up where you want them.